# Keeping track of iterations through list done inside function in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, recursion, dictionary

I have an interesting question that very well may be answered with "Do it another way."

I have a function that iterates through a list with a for loop. I call the function within itself on certain parameters, and keep iterating through the list from the point it was at. The issue is I would like to be able to jump out of the recursive call back into the top function but keep track of how far I went in the list and go on from there.

Basically I want something like this:

```
def iterate_list(listA)
    dictA = {}
    for pos,item in enumerate(listA):
        if item == 1:
            dictA[pos] = iterate_list(listA[pos])
            #At this point I want to go back to for loop (like continue does) except I want 
            #to be at the pos I was at when I left the sub function
            continue #? Don't think continue is what I want but its the closest thing I could 
            #find so I left it in for now
        elif item == 2:
            return dictA
        else:
            dictA[pos] = item
    return dictA

dictFinal = iterate_list(original_list)
```

So the end result is a dictionary of whatever is in the list (integers in this example but not always) except for some points when the key points to a sub dictionary. This is a simplified version of the code were I took out all the extra code that gets the keys and values (that bit works I tested it extensively) so what I'm putting in the dictionary here looks a little silly (but simulates what I'm doing well enough). Thanks for the help.

edit: A little more detail on the input and output as requested. The input is a list of strings that are mostly written as word : word, the output is the first word as the key, the second as the value for the dictionary. The parsing of the strings code is written and works. But there are some areas of repeated keys so I want those to go into a sub dictionary. So for example

```
Input = [Name: Bob, ID: 12345, Age: 99, Job: Dentist, Patient Name: John, Patient ID: 321, Patient Name: Susan, Patient ID: 666, Patient Name: Lucy, Patient ID: 087, Employees: 5, Address: 233 Main St, Phone: 555-5555]

Output = {Name : Bob, ID : 12345, Age : 99, Job : Dentist, Patient1 : {Patient Name : John, Patient ID : 321}, Patient2 : {Patient Name : Susan, Patient ID : 666}, Patient3 : {Patient Name : Lucy, Patient ID : 087}, Employees : 5, Address : 233 Main St, Phone : 555-5555}
```

If that makes sense. Let me know if more detail is needed.

Comment: You can just store a variable in the global scope and access it inside the function. This way it won't go to waste after the function is done each time.

Comment: Can you put an input/output sample?

Comment: Try using the break keyword instead of continue.  Break will exit the forloop and your recursive function will return to the previous.  The continue keyword just skips the loop's current iteration and goes on to the next.

Comment: @ConorPatrick I don't necessarily want to exit the for loop though, I just want to skip X iterations ahead where X is the number of iterations I went through in the sub function. If I break then I'll just exit out once I get to the top level.

Comment: @Allendar I guess I'm not sure exactly how you are saying to use said variable. I could use it to keep track of my location in the list, but one I leave the sub call of the function how do I force the for loop to jump to that point in the list?  Or am I misunderstanding completely what you were saying?

Comment: Using that variable is not that hard. You just declare a variable in the global scope and assign (and use) it in your function like `global my_variable`. As long as you don't have an interaction (GUI) or subprocesses in your application, then you don't have to worry about the occupation of that variable, because everything will just run serial. Once you enter a parallel instruction set, you will have to build logic in the function to lock the counter for each loop-cycle or something similar, so it can't get all messy. I hope you follow :)

Comment: @Allendar I follow to an extent I think. I have the variable, and it counts the loop cycles, but when I exit the recursive call and come back into the middle of the for loop in the top level function how do I get the for loop to skip ahead to where the global variable says it should be?

For example if I have global variable Z and the loop "for x in y" I go through the loop 10 times in a recursive call, so Z is 10, then come back out to the top level function, how do I make "for x in y" jump ahead 10 iterations? I might be missing something simple, I am still pretty new to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple answer would be to use an iterator. If you pass an iterator to a recursive call and it consumes some elements, when the recursive call returns, you'll continue where it left off:

```
def function(iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable):
    for thing in iterable:
        if some_condition(thing):
            function(iterable)
            continue
            # The next iteration of the loop will use
            # the first item the recursive call didn't.
```

This might not cut it, though; for example, you might need to go back a position or two in the list, and most Python iterators don't support that. In that case, you could write an iterator that allows you to unconsume elements, or you could iterate with an explicit index and put the index you stopped at into the return value.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for, works perfectly. I had gotten a "usable" setup going where I forced iterations through the loop to get to where I needed to be, but this way is much cleaner (and I'd guess more efficient though I don't know for sure). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) input list. List elements are tokens and grammar is simple but syntactic analysis is better to implemented with more (recursive) functions, depending on grammar definition.

From your example, [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) seems like:

```
<patient>       ::= <patient-id> <patient-name>  # Patient has 2 fields
<doctor-data>   ::= Name | ID | Age | Job        # Personal doctor data is combination of these data
<doctor>        ::= <doctor-data> <patient>*     # Doctor data is personal data and some patients
<hospital_data> ::= Employees | Address | Phone  # Hospital data fields
<hospital>      ::= <doctor>* <hospital_data>    # Hospital has doctors and additional data
```